# Predicting the next value of data points using LSTM and Keras having tensorflow as a backend

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a data with 65 samples. Example: 2697,2825,2136,2824,3473,2513,2538,3051,2737.9805,3133.849,2350.8695,6000,3121.225

I've divided the data in training and testing (train and test), scaled it and also supervised it. I have to predict what would be the 66th sample value.

2697,2825,2136,2824,3473,2513,2538,3051,2737.9805,3133.849,2350.8695,6000,3121.225, ?, ?, ?

I've tried various methods. One of them is:

`enter code here`

```
lstm_model = fit_lstm(train_scaled, 1, 100, 4)

train_reshaped = train_scaled[:, 0].reshape(len(train_scaled), 1, 1)

lstm_model.predict(train_reshaped, batch_size=1)

predictions = list()
expected = list()
for i in range(len(test_scaled)):
     X, y = test_scaled[i, 0:-1], test_scaled[i, -1]
     yhat = forecast_lstm(lstm_model, 1, X)
     # invert scaling
     yhat = invert_scale(scaler, X, yhat)

    yhat = pred(raw_values, yhat, len(test_scaled)-i+1)

    # store forecast
    predictions.append(yhat)

    expected_1 = raw_values[len(train) + i]

    expected.append(expected_1)

print('Predicted=%f, Expected=%f' % (yhat, expected_1))
```

Any lead will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.